# Principal fibre bundles with constant transition functions

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I guess this is not limited to principal bundles, however those are my primary interest in asking this question.

Let $(P,\pi,M,G)$ be a principal fibre bundle over $M$ with structure group $G$.

Assume that there exists an indexing set $\mathbb A$, and an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\mathbb A}$ of $M$ by local trivialization domains, such that for any nonempty $U_{\alpha\beta}=U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$ the transition functions $$ \psi_{\alpha\beta}:U_{\alpha\beta}\rightarrow G $$ are all constants.

What can we say about the bundle then? For a while I was under the impression that this means the bundle is trivial, however I doubt that's true.

Comment: It is called a flat bundle; equivalently, a bundle which admits a flat connection.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yeah I've been lead to this thought by considering bundles with flat connections. For a while I thought a frame bundle with this property needs to be over a parallelizable base, but on second thought this is obviously not true. I am learning about teleparallel gravity, where we assume a global parallel frame exists. It is said that it is equivalent to GR, however I haven't read any "global" analysis about it, and I am worried the global frame is a too stringent condition on the topology of spacetime and am trying to figure this out.

Comment: Do you know about flat Riemannian manifolds? Just think about the Klein bottle. Not every principal bundle admits a flat connection but many do.